# this.props.history.goBack goes back in browser history

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am making a web app with stack navigation and hamburger menu for "root elements". For that I use the `this.props.history.goBack` function, and check `this.props.history.length` to see if it is possible to do so. But I have a problem, that if I wander around in my app (website), then close it and enter its url in a browser tab, `this.props.history.length` will not be 0 or 1, but rather some value like 3 or 6, which makes the "go back" button appear, which, in turn, takes me back to the page that was open before I opened the app. Is it possible to check for that?

UPD: Here is the this.props.history when I open the website in a new tab:

```
[Log] Object (bundle.js, line 75006)

action: "REPLACE"

block: function()

createHref: function(location)

go: function(n)

goBack: function()

goForward: function()

length: 6

listen: function(listener)

location: Object

hash: ""

key: "zrwy59"

pathname: "/home"

search: ""

state: undefined

Object Prototype

push: function(path, state)

replace: function(path, state)

Object Prototype
```

Comment: Can you log `this.props.history` when you first enter your URL in the browser?

Comment: @Stretch0 which field?

Comment: It should return an object. The reason I want to see it is it should have some domain specific data which you can perform a check against.

Comment: @Stretch0 done.